# AJAX inconsistency in IE 8?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, post, ie-developer-tools

This is my code: (rather, the dodgy part thereof)

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    var requisicao=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    var requisicao=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

Ok. Sometimes this works fine, but sometimes the Javascript Debugger in IE tells me this:

> Object doesn't support this property or method model.js line 59 character 3

Which amounts to....

```
var requisicao=new XMLHttpRequest();
```

What bugs me is the fact that sometimes IE 8 accepts this and moves on but sometimes it chokes and doesn't work?

Any help is welcome

Thanks in advance

Comment: IE's reported error lines are basically random numbers. You're better off using the script debugger and having it jump to where the error really occured, rather than trying to figure out where this mythical "line 59" is.

Comment: Thats what i did actually. I'm using the script debugger whcih are a part of the Developer Tools on IE 8. It accurately tells me the line number and even jumps to the actul code and highlights the problem. So I'm thinking it's right... Also, because i was having this very problem with jQuery but now I changed back to regular javascript to try and nail down the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Apparently, in this case, Internet Explorer's line number is correct. This seems to be a common problem with Internet Explorer 8. There's a potential solution here: [Ajax app works in some browers, not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482177/problem-with-ie8-using-ajax).

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
try { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); }
catch (e) { try { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
catch (e) { try { xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); }
catch (e) { xmlhttp = false; }}}
```

<del>Unfortunately, Internet Explorer's line numbers aren't always accurate, since they are based on its own, internal serialization of your code. The error message is probably coming from a different line (hopefully near line 59).</del>

<del>I would check for places where you are calling a method on an object that could be set to different values for whatever reason.</del>

Comment: Yeah? At first, I was using jQuery. Then, the debugger told me the problem was in the jquery.js file, in this area, approximately:

xhr:A.XMLHttpRequest... 

And now I'm using regular javascript and it says the same? The same error and the same command? That cant be a coincidence?

Comment: @Felipe: I searched for that error with XMLHttpRequest and found this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482177/problem-with-ie8-using-ajax. You could try the solution from there (it has a lot more code, but you can take out the part you need).

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I dont really know why this works, but if you try and create the ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); object prior to creating the regular XMLHttpRequest it works.
  More info here http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread299941.html ... and thanks again to Mathhew Crumley